# Is it safe to thread concurrent database queries?

Tags: c#, sqlite, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm trying to improve upon this program that I wrote for work.  Initially I was rushed, and they don't care about performance or anything.  So, I made a horrible decision to query an entire database(a SQLite database), and then store the results in lists for use in my functions.  However, I'm now considering having each of my functions threaded, and having the functions query only the parts of the database that it needs.  There are ~25 functions.  My question is, is this safe to do?  Also, is it possible to have that many concurrent connections?  I will only be PULLING information from the database, never inserting or updating.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/355025/119477 its mostly the SQLite side of things that can be vexing

Answer (score 0):

The way I've had it described to me<sup>[*]</sup> is to have each concurrent thread open its own connection to the database, as each connection can only process one query or modification at a time. The group of threads with their connections can then perform concurrent reads easily. If you've got a significant problem with many concurrent writes causing excessive blocking or failure to acquire locks, you're getting to the point where you're exceeding what SQLite does for you (and should consider a server-based DB like PostgreSQL).

Note that you can also have a master thread open the connections for the worker threads if that's more convenient, but it's advised (for your sanity's sake if nothing else!) to only actually *use* each connection from one thread.

---

<sup>[* For a normal build of SQLite. It's possible to switch things off at build time, of course.]</sup>

Comment: I've been messing around lately with [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) as well, which you can run as a server or in-proc as well.  Might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no write concurrency, but it supports arbitrarily many connections that read at the same time.
Just ensure that every thread has its own connection.

Answer (score 0):

25 simultanious connections is not a smart idea. That's a huge number.

I usually create a multi-layered design for this problem. I send all requests to the database through a kind of ObjectFactory class that has an internal cache. The ObjectFactory will forward the request to a ConnectionPoolHandler and will store the results in its cache. This connection pool handler uses X simultaneous connections but dispatches them to several threads.

However, some remarks must be made before applying this design. You first have to ask yourself the following 2 questions:

- Is your application the only application that has access to this
  database?
- Is your application the only application that modifies data in this database?

If the first question is negatively, then you could encounter locking issues. If your second question is answered negatively, then it will be extremely difficult to apply caching. You may even prefer not to implement any caching it all.

Caching is especially interesting in case you are often requesting objects based on a unique reference, such as the primary key. In that case you can store the most often used objects in a Map. A popular collection for caching is an "LRUMap" ("Least-Recently-Used" map). The benifit of this collection is that it automatically arranges the most often used objects to the top. At the same time it has a maximum size and automatically removes items from the map that are rarely ever used.

A second advantage of caching is that each object exists only once. For example:

1. An Employee is fetched from the database.
2. The ObjectFactory converts the resultset to an actual object instance
3. The ObjectFactory immediatly stores it in cache.
4. A bit later, a bunch of employees are fetched using an SQL "... where name like "John%" statement.
5. Before converting the resultset to objects, the ObjectFactory first checks if the IDs of these records are perhaps already stored in cache.
6. Found a match ! Aha, this object does not need to be recreated.

There are several advantages to having a certain object only once in memory.

Last but not least in Java there is something like "Weak References". These are references that are references that in fact can be cleaned up by the garbage collector. I am not sure if it exists in C# and how it's called. By implementing this, you don't even have to care about the maximum amount of cached objects, your garbage collector will take care of it.